# If $x$ is a real and $0 < x < 4$, then $\frac{4}{x(4-x)} \geq 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

I got this exercise from the textbook Book of Proof, CH4 E12. I've tackle this problem in the following manner:

Suppose x is a real and $0 < x < 4$, it follows that,

\begin{align*}
&\Rightarrow 0 - 2 < x - 2 < 4 - 2 \\
&\Rightarrow     4 < (x - 2)^2 < 4\\
&\Rightarrow     0 \leq (x - 2)^2 < 4
\end{align*}

Since, $x(4 - x) = 4x - x^2 = 4 - (x - 2)^2$, then

$$\dfrac{4}{x(4 - x)} = \dfrac{4}{4 - (x - 2)^2}.$$

This expression is greater or equal to $1$ for
$0 \leq (x - 2)^2 < 4$. Thus,

$$\dfrac{4}{x(4 - x)} \geq 1.$$

I'm quite new to proof technique and I'm using this book to self-learn logic and proofing writing. My question is: is the solution stated above logically sound? Would my arguments be considered sufficient to prove that $P \Rightarrow Q$?

Comment: Please use Latex

Comment: No. Try to follow it with $x=2$. Is something wrong? Also, $4<k<4$ implies $k$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is actually quite nice, but there is one error:  It is incorrect to say that $0-2\lt x-2 \lt 4-2$ implies $4\lt(x-2)^2\lt4$.  What you want to say instead is something like

$$0-2\lt x-2\lt4-2\implies|x-2|\lt2\implies0\le(x-2)^2\lt4$$

Comment: Fixing that mistake and using the inequality 0 <= (x - 2)^2 to argue that Q is true would make the proof correct then?

Comment: @WPJR, yes, except you need more than just $0\le(x-2)^2$.  You also need the inequality $(x-2)^2\lt4$.

Comment: Yeah I meant a <= (x - 2)^2 < 4, Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint See that: $0\le x\le 4 $ implies $0\le 4-x\le 4$ and then,
$$0\le x(4-x) =-(x-2)^2+4\le4$$

Thus directly implies your inequality.$$\dfrac{4}{x(4 - x)} \geq 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

To get from $0−2<x−2<4−2$ to $4<(x−2)^2<4$ you have simply squared the entire inequality. This is invalid since you have not only led to a contradiction ($4 < k < 4$ implies no such $k$ exists), you have also mistakenly thought that if $a$ and $b$ are reals and $a < b$, then $a^2 < b^2$. This is clearly not true if $a$ and $b$ are not restricted in any other way. Since this step leads to a contradiction, the rest is invalid.

To create a logical and sound solution, the solution must not lead to any contradiction and cover all possible cases. One method to write a logical proof is to include as much (as necessary) details as possible. Try not to skip steps as it might lead to one missing some cases or using a "fact" that hasn't been shown to be true yet. When the details are there, make them clear and concise.

One possible method I propose for this problem is using the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). Since $0 < x < 4$, both $x$ and $(4-x)$ are positive. Use it on $x(4-x)$ to derive $\sqrt{x(4-x)} \le \frac{x+(4-x)}{2}$. You may continue from here on.

Comment: I like this approach very much. I will add the AM-GM inequality to my tool kit.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this proof by contradiction: We want to prove $P\rightarrow Q$ and we prove it by assuming $P$ and $\neg Q$, and getting a contradiction.

Suppose $0<x<4$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and the inequality $\dfrac{4}{x(x-4)}\geq 1$ does not hold.

Then we have $0<x,0<4-x$ (both follow from $0<x<4$) and $\dfrac{4}{x(x-4)}<1$, and we have:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{4}{x(4-x)}&<1 & &\\
4&<x(4-x) & &\text{[multiplying both sides by $x(x-4)>0$]}\\
0&<x(4-x)-4\\
0&<-x^2+4x-4\\
x^2-4x+4&<0\\
(x-2)^2&<0
\end{align*}

which is absurd because every squared real number is positive.

This contradiction allows us to conclude that $\dfrac{4}{(x-4)}\geq 1$.

Comment: The exercise requires direct proof of conditional statements P => Q, It does not consider contradictions at this stage. That said, I very much like your approach I will revisit it once learning contradiction proof techniques. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are right, my solution uses probably a more advanced method to somebody that is learning how to write proofs. Just now I really read your solution, and I think is quite nice. I would add one more thing to make it more clear: notice that $$\dfrac{4}{x(4 - x)} = \dfrac{4}{4 - (x - 2)^2}=\dfrac{[4-(x-2)^2] + (x-2)^2}{4 - (x - 2)^2}=1+\dfrac{(x-2)^2}{4-(x-2)^2},$$and the last summand is always positive.

Comment: Very neat. I will probably be posting more question in the future If I get stuck. Can I feel free to reach out to you for help? Thanks!

Comment: You can always feel free to reach out to this site for help